# Overlapping section names in UITableView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a container in my `UIControlView`.

This is the relevant part of **Storyboard**. The starting view is a `TabBarController`, that has a `TableView` (named `_Constructed_`) in its second tab. The Table is embedded in `NavigationController`. When user taps at a cell in this Table, he's taken (with a Show segue) to a `GameDetailViewController`, that has two containers - the upper one is `PageView` and the bottom one is `TableView`.[image: Storyboard]

The issue appears in this `TableView`. Even though I have constraints set up (width is the same superview's, height is from bottom tabBar to the upper Container, which has fixed height and width), both upper and bottom sides are kinda pushed in a way.

[image: Overlapping section]

Comment: You're definitely not giving us enough information. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve] that illustrates the problem and includes all the relevant code/storyboard details, as well as what you expect the output to be. You need to at least provide details of your `tableView:cellForIndexPath:`method, and probably height-related methods. If you're using auto-sizing, you need to provide details of your constraints.

Comment: Oh, actually I thought it's some minor issue that happens to a lot of newbies and is widely known. Knowing it's not the case, I'll add the code and more information ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this issue by merely restarting XCode and reopening the project a few times. Maybe it's some kind of a bug, I haven't changed my code in any way and it just started working.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you need to pay attention to the **Size Classes** you used. When you reopen your **Xcode**, it directs you back `AnyW, AnyH`. It might change the fixed size under some scenario. Also, make sure that you are testing using the same simulator.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Im not sure, but you can replace the header from the tableView and it would work right.

```
tableView.tableHeaderView = myPageView
```

If it's not the case you should manage the contentInset and contentOffset by yourself for your header and for the list.